# What is the difference between an ion-induced dipole attraction and just an ion-dipole attraction?

Tags: polarity, dipole

By what I've read, an **ion-induced dipole** attraction is a weak attraction that results when the approach of an ion creates a dipole in a ***non-polar*** atom or in a ***non-polar*** molecule by disturbing the arrangement of electrons in the non-polar species. So this is a dispersion/van-der-Waal force, I believe?

On the other hand, an **ion-dipole** attraction is a weak attraction that results when the approach of an ion interacts with the dipole in a ***polar*** atom or in a ***polar*** molecule. And so this wouldn't be a van-der-Waal force would it?

---

If what I said above happens to be true, does the same apply with **dipole-induced dipole** forces and just **dipole-dipole** forces?

In this scenario, a dipole-induced dipole attraction would be a weak attraction that results when the approach of an dipole (polar covalent bond) creates a dipole in a ***non-polar*** atom or in a ***non-polar*** molecule by disturbing the arrangement of electrons in the non-polar species. So this is a dispersion/van-der-Waal force too, right?

And a dipole-dipole attraction would be a weak attraction that results when the approach of an dipole that *already exists*  in a polar bond attracts with another dipole in another ***polar*** atom or in ***polar*** molecule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful to note the definition of a *van der Waal* force: **weak electric forces attracting neutral molecules to each other in gas** thus causing a gas to deviate from an ideal gas.

So, there are three types of these forces

1. Dipole-dipole force
2. Dipole-induced dipole force
3. London dispersion force

It becomes clear that forces involving ions do not fit van de Waals forces as the molecules involved must be neutral.

An ion-induced dipole force is not a dispersion force, either (as dispersion forces are a subset of van der Waals), and with ion-dipole forces, ion-induced dipole forces have a category of it's own

A dipole-induced dipole force is a van der Waal force but not a dispersion force

Comment: So what exactly is a London Dispersion force? I've been reading that it is sort of like a "Induced Dipole-Induced Dipole" interaction, where if neutral atom "x" is induced by a permanent dipole, then neutral atom "y" which next to "x" also gets induced by "x's" temporary dipole. Then neutral atom "z" gets induced by "y's" temporary dipole. Kind of like a chain reaction? If not, then what is it?

Comment: An asymmetric distribution of electrons by chance can cause a temporary dipole, causing a slight positive and slight negative end, and the London Dispersion Forces involves the attraction of such atoms with dipoles. So it is an induced dipole-induced dipole, but not by the mechanism you described